# Copy Conditional Formatting 3-Color Scheme to another tab

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, conditional-formatting

I have one sheet, ***Tab 1***, with a 38x12 grid of values ranging from -30 to +30. I applied the traditional 3-color scheme conditional formatting to the data, which shows all shades of the spectrum between the three colors (came out great...)

On ***Tab 2***, I have a grid (38x12, same relative order of cells) with qualitative data in the cells. I want to apply the same color scheme to the grid on ***Tab 2*** but keep the quantitative data only on the first tab.

I came up with a weaker solution where I use a formula in conditional formatting to link the grid in ***Tab 2*** to ***Tab 1*** and manually create 5 rules in which I choose a dark green, light green, yellow, light red, and dark red to apply based on the values of ***Tab 1***. This does not have the same effect as the full spectrum though.

Basically, what I need is for excel to have a Paste Special -> Background color but unfortunately that's not yet an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't seem this is possible with VBA.

But, here's a ***ridiculous*** work-around.

Copy your cells from tab1 and paste them into microsoft word

Then copy that from word back to excel. Delete the values. Now you can format paint them to the other tab.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now, format paint.

[image]